# I have a list of images. On clicking each imageView, I want to make a call from the app. But I'm receiving error

Tags: android

```
 int[] imgid = {R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_up);

    for (int i = 0; i < imgid.length; i++) {

        ImageView phnImg = (ImageView) findViewById(imgid[i]);
```

Make call

```
        phnImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));

                //checks for permission before placong the call
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(PickUpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PickUpActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                } else {

                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

Answer (score 4):

You want a list of id, but your code get a list of drawable, that why you get this error.

```
int[] imgid = {R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call, R.drawable.call};
```

So please correct it as below

```
int[] imgid = {R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id, R.id.image_id};
```

`image_id` is your id which is in your layout xml file.